# Скрипт "Мне нравится"

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, javascript, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Делаю скрипт на отзывах, чтобы была кнопка мне нравится, нажал, тут же отобразилось число рядом, соответственно все это хранится в БД в виде числа, а как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку число в БД в соответствующей ячейке увеличивалось на единицу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table` SET `quantity`=`quantity`+1 WHERE `item_id`=n
```